# How to divide the product quantity based on the group quantity

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with list of products with quantities and their group. I want to divide them equally based on the product group quantity. Each group may contain one or more products.

The following table shows the products and their group wise quantity

```
SortOrder   ProductID   ToolGroup   ToolGroupQty    Quantity
1           PRD1            A1         180          900
2           PRD2            A2         77           125
3           PRD3            A2                      125
4           PRD4            A2                      135
5           PRD5            A3         129          125
6           PRD6            A3                      520
7           PRD7            A4         77           385
```

The actual result should be as follows

```
SortOrder   ProductID   ToolGroup   Quantity    Group
1           PRD1           A1       180          1
2           PRD2           A2       77           1
5           PRD5           A3       125          1
6           PRD6           A3       4            1
7           PRD7           A4       77           1
1           PRD1           A1       180          2
2           PRD2           A2       48           2
3           PRD3           A2       29           2
6           PRD6           A3       129          2
7           PRD7           A4       77           2
1           PRD1           A1       180          3
3           PRD3           A2       77           3
6           PRD6           A3       129          3
7           PRD7           A4       77           3
1           PRD1           A1       180          4
3           PRD3           A2       19           4
4           PRD4           A2       58           4
6           PRD6           A3       129          4
7           PRD7           A4       77           4
1           PRD1           A1       180          5
4           PRD4           A2       77           5
6           PRD6           A3       129          5
7           PRD7           A4       77           5
```

The sum of each group should be equal. For this case 463. Each ToolGroup's SUM should be equal to the respective toolgroup quantity.

The sum of each product should be equal to the given quantity in the above table.

Please help me on this. I have tried many approaches. Nothing worked out for me.

Please find the code I tried below

```
declare @CombinationGroupTable table(SortOrder int,ProductID nvarchar(50),Combination   nvarchar(20),Tools  int,ToolGroup nvarchar(10),ToolGroupQty int,Market nvarchar(20),Quantity int,isUpdated char(10))

insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(1,'PRD1','A',7,'A1',  180,'M0002',900,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(2,'PRD2','A',3,'A2',  77, 'M0003',125,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(3,'PRD3','A',NULL,'A2',   NULL,'M0004',125,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(4,'PRD4','A',NULL,'A2',   NULL,'M0004',135,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(5,'PRD5','A',5,'A3',  128,'M0001',125,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(6,'PRD6','A',NULL,'A3',NULL,  'M0003',520,NULL)
insert into @CombinationGroupTable values(7,'PRD7','A',3,'A4',  77,'M0004', 385, NULL)

select * from @CombinationGroupTable

declare @SortOrder int,@productID nvarchar(100),@Quantity int,@shift char(1),@prevQty int,@productCode nvarchar(100)
declare @Combination nvarchar(20),@Market nvarchar(50),@Tools int, @prevTools int,@prevComb nvarchar(10), @ToolGroupName nvarchar(20),@tGroupCount int
declare @MaxgroupID nvarchar(20),@NextGroup nvarchar(20), @MaxComb int,@LastSortOrder int,@toCompensate int,@ToolGroup nvarchar(20), @ToolGroupQty int
declare @minOrder int , @maxOrder int, @combProdID nvarchar(100), @combMarket nvarchar(20), @combQty int, @shiftFact int,@combTools int,@combToolsGroup nvarchar(10), @ToolQty int, @toolshiftQty int,@combOrder int, @CToolGroup nvarchar(20)
declare @shiftQty int = 464,@ToolsCount int = 18
declare  @ProdQty table(ID int identity(1,1),SortOrder int,ProductID nvarchar(100),Quantity int,Market nvarchar(10),GroupNo int,ToolGroup nvarchar(20))
declare @RID int,@SOrder int,@CCombination nvarchar(20), @CTotal int, @CompensationQty int,@LastQty int,@RemaininQty int,@PreviousQty int,@ctoolgroupQty int, @tgCompensate int

                declare planSchedule cursor for select SortOrder,ProductID,Combination,Tools,ToolGroup,ToolGroupQty,Market,Quantity from @CombinationGroupTable order by SortOrder
                open planSchedule
                fetch next from planSchedule into @sortOrder,@ProductID,@Combination,@Tools,@ToolGroup,@ToolGroupQty,@Market,@Quantity
                while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
                begin

                select  top 1 @MaxComb = isnull(GroupNo,1) from @ProdQty group by GroupNo Order by CAST(GroupNo as int) desc
                set @NextGroup= case when isnull(@LastQty,0) < @shiftQty then isnull(@MaxComb,1) else @MaxComb+1 end

                select @minOrder= MIN(SortOrder),@maxOrder = MAX(SortOrder) from @CombinationGroupTable

                    while @minOrder <= @maxOrder
                    begin

                        select @combMarket= Market,@combQty = Quantity,@combProdID = ProductID,@combTools= Tools,@combToolsGroup= toolGroup,@ctoolgroupQty= ToolGroupQty from @CombinationGroupTable where Combination = @Combination and SortOrder= @minOrder and tools is not null                        

                        select @ToolQty =   CASE WHEN  @LastQty < @shiftQty THEN (CAST(@shiftQty-@LastQty as numeric)/@ToolsCount * @combTools) ELSE (CAST(@shiftQty as numeric)/@ToolsCount *  @combTools) END

                        if(isnull(@Tools,'') <> '' and isnull(@combTools,'') <> '')
                        begin

                            if((select count(*) from @CombinationGroupTable where ToolGroup = @ToolGroup and Sortorder = @minOrder)> 1)
                            select count(*),ToolGroup from @CombinationGroupTable where ToolGroup = @ToolGroup  and Sortorder = @minOrder group by ToolGroup

                            else
                            begin                                   

                                    if(@combQty >= @ToolQty)
                                    begin



                                        if((select isnull(sum(quantity),0) from @ProdQty where ToolGroup = @combToolsGroup and GroupNo = @NextGroup) <= @ctoolgroupQty)
                                        begin
                                                insert into @ProdQty values(@minOrder,@combProdID,@ToolQty,@combMarket,@NextGroup,@combToolsGroup)
                                        end
                                        else
                                        begin                                                                                   


                                            set @tgCompensate = @ToolQty -(select sum(quantity) from @ProdQty where groupno = @nextgroup and ToolGroup = @combToolsGroup)                                           

                                            insert into @ProdQty values(@minOrder,@combProdID,@tgCompensate,@combMarket,@NextGroup,@combToolsGroup)

                                            update @CombinationGroupTable set Quantity= Quantity - @tgCompensate,ToolGroupQty= @ToolQty,isUpdated='Y' where productID= @combProdID and ToolGroup = @combToolsGroup


                                        end
                                    end 

                                    else
                                    begin

                                        insert into @ProdQty values(@minOrder,@combProdID,@combQty,@combMarket,@NextGroup,@combToolsGroup)                                                                              

                                        update @CombinationGroupTable set Tools = @Tools where ToolGroup= @ToolGroup and isnull(isUpdated,'N')='N' and SortOrder= @minOrder + 1

                                    end

                            end

                        update @CombinationGroupTable set Quantity = case when @combQty >= @ToolQty then (Quantity-@ToolQty) else (Quantity-@combQty) end,isUpdated='Y'  where ProductID = @combProdID                      

                        end

                        set @minOrder= @minOrder+1
                        set @combMarket= '' set @combQty = 0 set @combProdID = '' set @combTools = 0
                    end

                    set @LastQty = 500000

                fetch next from planSchedule into @sortOrder,@ProductID,@Combination,@Tools,@ToolGroup,@ToolGroupQty,@Market,@Quantity
                end

                close planSchedule
                deallocate planSchedule


                select SortOrder,ProductID,ToolGroup,Quantity,GroupNo [Group] from @ProdQty
```

Expected result in excel format

[image]

Comment: *"I have tried many approaches. Nothing worked out for me."* so what *have* you tried? It's difficult for us to see where you went wrong when we can't see the SQL you used. What happens when the value doesn't fit into equally into a set? So if you have 120 as a total, and 3 groups, but need to split it into sets of 50, what happens?

Comment: Please check the question again. I have included my code.

Comment: What is the logic behind the division of `ProductID` (PRD3,PRD3 & PRD6) which has no `ToolGroupQty` ?

Comment: PRD3 belongs to ToolGroup A2, So the ToolGroupQty for A2 is 77.

Comment: PRD6 belongs to ToolGroup A3, So the ToolGroupQty for A3 is 129.

Answer (score 0):

The query which you uses has a `CURSOR` which is very expensive in terms of computation cost, I'd recommend using the `RECURSIVE CTE` approach to divide the product quantity.

Assumptions I made are

- `ToolGroupQty` field should have values in it, you can auto fill the values in advance

The following query should do what you want:

```
DECLARE @CombinationGroupTable TABLE (SortOrder INT,ProductID NVARCHAR(50),Combination NVARCHAR(20),Tools INT,ToolGroup NVARCHAR(10),ToolGroupQty INT,Market NVARCHAR(20),Quantity INT,isUpdated CHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @CombinationGroupTable VALUES(1,'PRD1','A',7,'A1',  180,'M0002',900,NULL)
INSERT INTO @CombinationGroupTable VALUES(2,'PRD2','A',3,'A2',  77, 'M0003',125,NULL)
INSERT INTO @CombinationGroupTable VALUES(3,'PRD3','A',NULL,'A2',   77,'M0004',125,NULL)
INSERT INTO @CombinationGroupTable VALUES(4,'PRD4','A',NULL,'A2',   77,'M0004',135,NULL)
INSERT INTO @CombinationGroupTable VALUES(5,'PRD5','A',5,'A3',  128,'M0001',125,NULL)
INSERT INTO @CombinationGroupTable VALUES(6,'PRD6','A',NULL,'A3',128,  'M0003',520,NULL)
INSERT INTO @CombinationGroupTable VALUES(7,'PRD7','A',3,'A4',  77,'M0004', 385, NULL)

;WITH cte (ProductID, ToolGroupQty, Quantity, Quantity_calc, [Group]) as (
    SELECT ProductID
        ,ToolGroupQty
        ,Quantity
        ,CASE WHEN Quantity>ToolGroupQty THEN ToolGroupQty 
            ELSE Quantity END 
        ,1
    FROM @CombinationGroupTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ProductID
        ,ToolGroupQty
        ,t1
        ,CASE WHEN t1>ToolGroupQty THEN ToolGroupQty 
            ELSE t1 END
        ,[Group] + 1
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(Quantity-ToolGroupQty)) AS t(t1) WHERE t1 > 0
    )

SELECT ProductID
    ,ToolGroupQty
    ,Quantity_calc AS [Quantity]
    ,[Group]
FROM cte 
ORDER BY [Group], [ProductID]
```

The result is as below,

```
ProductID   ToolGroupQty Quantity   Group
PRD1        180          180        1
PRD2        77           77         1
PRD3        77           77         1
PRD4        77           77         1
PRD5        128          125        1
PRD6        128          128        1
PRD7        77           77         1
PRD1        180          180        2
PRD2        77           48         2
PRD3        77           48         2
PRD4        77           58         2
PRD6        128          128        2
PRD7        77           77         2
PRD1        180          180        3
PRD6        128          128        3
PRD7        77           77         3
PRD1        180          180        4
PRD6        128          128        4
PRD7        77           77         4
PRD1        180          180        5
PRD6        128          8          5
PRD7        77           77         5
```

Comment: Mjoy Thank you. But your query doesn't return the actual result. Please refer the second table in my question.

Comment: The sum of each group should be 463. But in this It goes beyond that.